# AKS - public Load Balancer / Openfaas - "Cannot connect to OpenFaaS on URL: https://..."

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer, openfaas

Situation: I have an AKS cluster that I'm trying to load my project into from localhost.
When I launch my Ansible scripts to get the project running, I need to log in to openfaas but I encounter this error:

```
>     ...\nCannot connect to OpenFaaS on URL: https:(...).com/faas. Get \"https://(..).com/faas/system/functions\": dial tcp
> xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while
> awaiting headers)", "stdout_lines": ["WARNING! Using --password is
> insecure, consider using: cat ~/faas_pass.txt | faas-cli login -u user
> --password-stdin", "Calling the OpenFaaS server to validate the credentials...", "Cannot connect to OpenFaaS on URL:
> https://(...).com/faas. Get
> \"https://(...).com/faas/system/functions\": dial tcp
> xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx: i/o timeout (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"]}
```

I have a PUBLIC Load Balancer I created from a yaml file and it's linked to the DNS (...).com / IP address of LB created.

My loadbalancer.yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: loadbalancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

My ingress file:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: openfaas
spec:
  rules:
  - host: (...).com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: openfaas
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /faas
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - (...).com
    secretName: (...).com
---
```

I haven't found many tutorials that have the same situation or they use internal Load Balancers.

Is this **Azure** that's blocking the communication? a Firewall problem?
Do I need to make my LB internal instead of external?

I saw a source online that stated this:

> If you expose a service through the normal LoadBalancer with a public
> ip, it will not be accessible because the traffic that has not been
> routed through the azure firewall will be dropped on the way out.
> Therefore you need to create your service with a fixed internal ip,
> internal LoadBalancer and route the traffic through the azure firewall
> both for outgoing and incoming traffic.
> https://denniszielke.medium.com/setting-up-azure-firewall-for-analysing-outgoing-traffic-in-aks-55759d188039

But I'm wondering if it's possible to bypass that..

Any help is greatly apprecated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out afterwards that Azure already provides a LB, so you do not need to create one. Not a firewall issue.
Go to "Load Balancing" -> "Frontend IP Configuration" and choose the appropriate IP.